# Multi-threaded compression in rasterio?

Tags: python, performance, rasterio, parallel-processing, big-data

For writing large raster files (e.g. satellite image GeoTIFFs) to disk, the throughput rate tends to be limited by the compression algorithm rather than by the raw disk IO. (Benchmarks: [1](https://kokoalberti.com/articles/geotiff-compression-optimization-guide/), [2](https://digital-geography.com/geotiff-compression-comparison/).) This is good news because data compression (computation) is far easier to parallelise than file IO generally is. Can we take advantage of this in python?

When using the `rasterio` python library, is there any way to use multithreading to write a large file more quickly? (For example, is there a way to set `GDAL_NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS`?)

Comment: Only with some compression methods, from the driver https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html NUM_THREADS=number_of_threads/ALL_CPUS works with DEFLATE or LZMA which perhaps could be set like https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/image_options.html not all compression methods support multithreading, their driver would have to be compiled as thread safe and aware of this creation option.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, although this seems not to be mentioned in the documentation.

If you include `num_threads=8` or `num_threads='all_cpus'` as an argument to `rasterio.open` then multithreading will be enabled (for writing of compressed data).

Example:

```py
import numpy as np, rasterio
size = 16384
chunk = 512
with rasterio.open('test.tiff', 'w', driver='GTiff', nodata=0,
                   width=size, height=size, count=1, dtype=np.float32,
                   tiled=True, blockxsize=256, blockysize=256, 
                   compress='lzw', num_threads='all_cpus') as dst: 
    for i in range(0, size, chunk):
        for j in range(0, size, chunk):
            data = np.random.random((chunk, chunk)).astype(np.float32)
            dst.write(data, window=rasterio.windows.Window(i, j, chunk, chunk), indexes=1)
```

Alternatively, you can temporarily set the global configuration:

```py
with rasterio.Env(GDAL_NUM_THREADS='ALL_CPUs'):
    ...
```